# Remove MSSQL database out of FCI

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I have three database nodes, node 1 & 2 are participating in HA using Failover Cluster Instance.  Node 3 is acting as DR using SQL Always On Availability Group similar to the image below:

[image]

I really want to get rid of the HA portion so that I only have node 1 and node 3 left.  If I don't care about node 2, how can I remove this correctly so node 1 is no longer participate in FCI?

When I look at the the FCI role in Window Failover Cluster Manager, I see the option to Delete, is it that simple?  My inner voice is screaming no because clustering the opposite of simple.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would evict Node1, and rebuild it with new storage.  Install a stand-alone SQL instance on the new Node1, add it to the cluster and add it to the AG.  Then remove Node2 from the AG, uninstall the FCI on Node2, and evict it from the cluster.

That way you keep the AG, avoid installing stuff on a production server, and replace your 2-node FCI with a fresh-built standalone instance.

Comment: You'll also need to consider your cluster's quorum configuration. Having only 2 voters isn't a good setup, particularly with the two nodes in different data centers. Having a 3rd voter in Data Center A would be my suggestion (either another cluster node, or a file share witness, most likely)

Comment: Or cloud quorum.  But with only 2 nodes, and no automatic failover, you can also remove the vote of the remote node.

Comment: If rebuilding a node to be standalone isn't possible/desirable option, a single-node FCI is a valid configuration.

Comment: Yeah, removing the vote works, too. But if you skip adjusting quorum and just evict the node, it'll likely be painful.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily choose a cloud witness, because then all three voters are in different locations and if the network is flaky, it can cause some mysterious problems. Cloud Witness is a better fit if you've got multiple nodes per geo.

Comment: It won't clean up the metadata in the cluster database this way because the instance wasn't uninstalled.

Comment: Added a step to uninstall the FCI once it's out of the AG.

Answer (score 2):

> If I don't care about node 2, how can I remove this correctly so node 1 is no longer participate in FCI?

There is no option to change from an FCI to a stand-alone instance. You'll need to install a stand-alone instance on Node 1, restore the databases (unless re-using the same disks, though be careful as the sharing will need to be removed and the disks can't be reused until the FCI is destroyed), then use the `Remove Node` option for Node 2 (must be run on Node 2).

At this point you'll have Node 1 and Node 3. Node 1 is still an FCI. You'll want to drop the entire AG.

Upon success use `Remove Node` for Node 1. At this point if re-using the disks, you can attach the databases to Node 1 Stand-Alone, otherwise they should be restored, if not already completed.

This will now put you at Node 1 Stand-Alone and Node 3 Stand-Alone. Use your favorite method to repoint clients to the old name if you wish, if not, continue on.

Setup the AG between the new Node 1 Stand-Alone and Node 3 Stand-Alone.

> When I look at the the FCI role in Window Failover Cluster Manager, I see the option to Delete, is it that simple? My inner voice is screaming no because clustering the opposite of simple.

Your inner voice is correct, do not do this. I'm glad you listened to it!

Comment: Sean, what do you think of my idea?  Look OK?